# simple_xml - Assigning variable to tag - only returning first

Tags: php, mysql, xml, simplexml, opencart

I'm trying to create an XML importer to load products from a POS system to an online store.

I'm wanting to go about this by getting the XML export from the POS system, process it and put the values directly into the multiple tables of the database.

The beginning of the code looks like this however I've already ran into a stumbling block.

```
<?php
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('product.xml');

$ProductName            = $xml->Product->Name;
$ProductDescription     = $xml->Product->Description;
$IsNew = str_replace("false", "0", $xml->Product->IsNew) // Sets False to 0 instead of false

echo $ProductName . "<br />";
echo $ProductDescription . "<br />";
echo $IsNew;
?>
```

So far I'm just trying to get the data from the XML Tags, put them in variables, and echo them so I see that I'm getting the right results.

This is only returning the details of the first product of the XML file (from over a thousand). I was expecting it to get the Name+Description+IsNew for every product. I'm assuming it needs to be in a while statement, but I can't figure out how to apply this with simple_xml

The XML structure looks like this.

```
<PRODUCTS>
      <PRODUCT>
              <UPDATETYPE>
              <STYLECODE>
              <NAME>
              <DESCRIPTION>
              ...etc...
              <ITEMS>
                    <ITEM>
                         <CODE>
                         <BARCODE>
                         <SIZE>
                         <PRICE>
                         ...etc...
                    </ITEM>
                    <ITEM>
                    ...etc...
                    </ITEM>
              </ITEMS>
     </PRODUCT>
     <PRODUCT>
     ...etc...
     </PRODUCT>
</PRODUCTS>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to traverse `Product` as an Array:

```
foreach($xml->Product as $_product){
  echo $_product->Name . "<br/>";
  echo $_product->Description . "<br/>";
  echo $_product->IsNew ? "true" : "false";
}
```

Comment: Thank-you for your reply philwinkle, this worked. I've edit the original post to include the XML structure. Do I then run further foreach arrays for Categories and Items, if so how would this look?
Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I hit enter and didn't finish the comment, please see above.

Comment: Never mind I think I've figured it out.

`foreach($xml->Product->Categories as $_categories)
      echo $_categories->Category;`

Comment: Yes, but it depends on how you want to display it. I would look into `array_map` which will map a custom function to run on every node.

Comment: At the moment I'm only echoing the variables to ensure I'm getting the correct results. Once I've got all of the information into it's own variable I will eventually be entering the variables into the database so provided it works I'll be happy. I will look into array_map to see if that's a better way then above - I'm a complete newbie at PHP but like to get out of my depth and give it a go.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm running into a problem using the variables in the mysql_query
Code is:

`mysql_select_db("snapbacks", $con);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO product (product_id, model, qty, sku, price, minimim, sort_order, status) VALUES ($_items->Item->Code, $_product->Name, $_items->Item->StockOnHand, $_items->Item->Code, $_items->Item->Price, '1', '1', '1')");

mysql_close($con);

 }
 
echo "done";`
I've tried the variables in single and double quotes but nothing is happening. I've simplified it to just inserting '1' into product_id to ensure the connection is good, and it is.

Comment: I realised they weren't their own variables so I assigned a variable and got the first only one to insert correctly like so: `                    $product_id =  $_items->Item->Code;
     $model = $_product->Name;

mysql_select_db("snapbacks", $con);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO product (product_id, model) VALUES ('$product_id', '$model')");

mysql_close($con);
`

That will insert the first - do I need to do a foreach or while in the SQL to insert all of them? Now I'm getting a bit confused.

Comment: It depends on how your query is written. I'd output the query to an $sql var first and then var_dump it so you can see whether the object properties in your $_items is being concatenated correctly (or even evaluated at all.)  If so, you probably want to foreach over $_items for $_item.